# Setting up a local version of site: config settings/issues

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, configuration, localhost

I've been attempting to set up a version of my website on my computer so that I stop making live updates on my website. The website runs on a PHP based CMS.

I posted a question earlier: [mysql connect - Moving my website to a local host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930556/mysql-connect-moving-my-website-to-a-local-host)

The question was about mysql-connect - the outcome was that I connected my database to my localhost as opposed to the current live host.

Now, the local version of my site loads except all styling is gone and the nav links do not work. I suspect the answer may be to do with the same file I edited in the question above: application/config/database.php

Here is what the code looked like originally:

```
$config['default'] = array(
    'benchmark' => TRUE,
    'persistent' => FALSE,
    'connection' => array(
        'type' => 'mysql',
        'user' => 'mywebsite',
        'pass' => 'somestringoftext',
        'host' => 'mywebsitecom.fatcowmysql.com',
        'port' => FALSE,
        'socket' => FALSE,
        'database' => 'mywebsiteDB4',
```

Then I changed it to this:

```
$config['default'] = array(
    'benchmark' => TRUE,
    'persistent' => FALSE,
    'connection' => array(
        'type' => 'mysql',
        'user' => 'root',
        'pass' => '',// Since it's on local host there is no password right now
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => FALSE,
        'socket' => FALSE,
        'database' => 'mywebsite',//this is what I called the DB I created and imported to in PHPmyadmin
```

It may be that this all looks correct and the issue lies elsewhere. I have a suspicion that it could be to do with the .htaccess file as, when I initially set up the site, I had issues with that, except all I had to do was set permissions. Thing is, the way the local version appears right now is very similar to how it looked when the .htaccess file was not "working".

I realize that I've just dropped a bunch of code and said "help"! I'm really stuck on where to look next. If anyone does have any ideas I'd be grateful to hear them. If any further info could help anyone with suspect ideas please let me know and I'l update.

Answer (score 2):

If site loads and you can see at page data taken from database, it means, what you DB connection is OK.
Since you can't see styling and menu not works, it means what you .JS/.CSS files not loaded correctly from you local server.
You can use addon FireFox called FireBug and here "Net" tab, to see which files loaded correctly and which not. For not loaded files you will need or change path to include it in you HTML file or change files location in you local filesystem